# makemigrations not able to find app within INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations

I am trying to port an existing django 1.4 project to django 1.7

Here is my tree structure before I ported the project to django 1.7

```
Project
 - MainApp
    - manage.py
    - settings.py
    - another_sub_app
    - another_sub_app2
```

While porting the project I had to move manage.py and sub_apps one level up.

```
Project
 - another_sub_app
 - another_sub_app2
 - manage.py
 - MainApp
  - settings.py
```

I used "South" for database migrations and had to use "python manage.py schemamigration " to make migrations. Now (after porting) I will be using "python manage.py makemigrations " to migrate app specific model changes.

However, while running "python manage.py makemigrations " I am getting:

> App 'app_name' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?

I have the app under INSTALLED_APPS and due to the structural changes I made I also tried including . inside INSTALLED_APPS. But this shows the same error again.

My question is has anyone tried porting a project to django 1.7 and has had similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried porting a project to django 1.7. However, I use django 1.7 and your settings.py should look like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'your_app_name',  #In your case, MainApp
    'your_app_name',  #In your case, another_sub_app
    'your_app_name',  #In your case, another_sub_app2
)
```

And the tree structure is

```
Project
  - Project
    - settings.py
  - MainApp
  - another_sub_app
  - another_sub_app2
  - manage.py
```